# How do I query documents where an entry in a sub-array matches all conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Below is my  rolesandresponsibilities collection document's

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58b6c380734d1d48176c9e69"
    },
    "role": "Admin",
    "resource": [
        {
            "id": "blog",
            "permissions": [
                "read",
                "update",
                "delete"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "user",
            "permissions": [
                "create",
                "read",
                "update",
                "delete"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "journal",
            "permissions": [
                "create",
                "read",
                "update",
                "delete"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58b7db3cf36d285019ea175f"
    },
    "role": "Manager",
    "resource": [
        {
            "id": "blog",
            "permissions": [
                "read",
                "update",
                "delete"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "user",
            "permissions": [
                "create",
                "read",
                "update",
                "delete"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "journal",
            "permissions": [
                "create",
                "read",
                "update",
                "delete"
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to check Admin has create access or not. 
I have written query like this

```
var check = { $and: [ { 'role':req.body.role, },  { 'resource.id':'blog'},{'resource.permissions':'create'} ] }
Rolesandresponsibilitie.find(check).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, rolesandresponsibilities) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (! rolesandresponsibilities) return res.status(404).send('Not Found'); };
        return res.status(200).send('Found'); }

    });
```

I am Getting Undefined

MY Expectation :

for example 1:

role =  Admin

id   =  blog

permissions = create

i should get response Not Found because Admin has only

"permissions": [
                "read",
                "update",
                "delete"
            ]

above 3 permissions

example 2 :

role =  Admin

id   =  blog

permissions = read

i should get response Found because Admin has read permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $elemMatch if you want to query in an array of sub documents, and you want to put condition per sub document basis.

```
var check = { $and: [ { 'role':req.body.role, },  { resource: { $elemMatch: { 'id': 'blog', 'permissions': 'create' } } }  ] }
```

Change the condition as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

$elemMatch is what you need and it will simplify the query.
By default mongo will treat properties in the query as an $and statement so there is no need to add that here.

A simpler query would be

```
var check = {
    'role':req.body.role,
    'resource':{
        '$elemMatch': {
            'id': 'blog',
            'permissions': 'create'
        }
     }
}

Rolesandresponsibilitie.find(check).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, rolesandresponsibilities) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (! rolesandresponsibilities) return res.status(404).send('Not Found'); };
    return res.status(200).send('Found'); }

});
```

The current issue you are having is because querying on

```
'resource.id':blog and 'resource.permissions':create
```

is that you have elements in the array that match both filters.
It simply checks the resource array to se if something has id=blog and if something has permissions=create, and the results don't necessarily have to be the same entry in the array.

Best of luck!

Comment: No problem, I struggled with this when I was starting out with mongodb.
Glad you find it helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501008/how-to-do-find-in-node-and-mongodb .help