# How to do find in node and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my 'usergroups' data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58f7537ec422895572e988a1"
    },
    "name": "aaa",
    "groupname": "group north,group south",
    "mobilenumber": "0509867865",
    "userid": "6035555c16"

}
```

here my 'groups' collection data's

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58e5eb3c035555c33f979daf"
    },
    "groupname": "group north",
    "message": [
        {
            "val": "hai how are you",
            "key": "1"
        },
        {
            "val": "i am fine",
            "key": "2"
        }

    ]
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "3c035555c33f979daf58e5eb"
    },
    "groupname": "group south",
    "message": [
        {
            "val": "testing",
            "key": "1"
        }

    ]
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55c3c035533f979f58e5ebda"
    },
    "groupname": "group east",
    "message": [
        {
            "val": "where are you from",
            "key": "1"
        }

    ]
}
```

In Usergroup I am trying to get the `groupname` based on `mobilenumber` and I have two groups: `group north` and `group south`. After getting groupname I need to fetch the message. How can I write this to find the condition for this. My goal is to send `group north, group south` message to the user.

```
Usergroup.findOne({
            mobilenumber: 0509867865
        },
        function(err, usergroup) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            if (!usergroup) {
                return res.status(404).send('Not Found');
            }
            console.log(usergroup.groupname);
        //group north ,group south
            Group.find({
                    groupname: 
                },
                function(err, group) {
                    if (err) {
                        return handleError(res, err);
                    }

                    return res.json(group);
                });
        });
```

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: i am using mongolab

Comment: http://docs.mlab.com/ops/#current-version. Can you check using this link ?

Comment: mongod version: 3.2.11 (MMAPv1)

Comment: Can you upgrade to 3.4 by any chance ? I'll add a solution just for future readers anyways.

Comment: why may i kno the reason

Comment: There is `$split` operator only available from 3.4 version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142114/discussion-between-its-me-and-veeram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$in` operator:

```
Usergroup.findOne({
            mobilenumber: 0509867865
        },
        function(err, usergroup) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            if (!usergroup) {
                return res.status(404).send('Not Found');
            }
            console.log(usergroup.groupname);
        //group north ,group south
            Group.find({
                    groupname: { $in: usergroup.groupname.split(",") } 
                },
                function(err, group) {
                    if (err) {
                        return handleError(res, err);
                    }

                    return res.json(group);
                });
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867811/how-to-do-user-already-there-update-if-not-there-create-in-particular-collecti

Comment: I will try to answer once I reach a computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below aggregation for `3.4` version.

The query will `$match` documents in the `usergroups` collection with the `mobilenumber` followed by `$split` to split the `groupnames` and `$lookup` the `groupname` in the `groups` collection for `messages`. Final step is to `$unwind` the `mobile_group` array to `$project` the `messages` for each `groupname`.

```
db.usergroups.aggregate([
    { $match: { mobilenumber:"0509867865" } },
    { $project: { groupname:{ $split: [ "$groupname", ',' ] }  } },
    { $lookup:
        {
          from: "groups",
          localField: "groupname",
          foreignField: "groupname",
          as: "mobile_group"
        }
   },
   {$unwind:"$mobile_group"},
   { $project : { groupname:"$mobile_group.groupname", "messages" : "$mobile_group.message" } }
])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542270/how-can-i-combine-multiple-collection-into-one-collection-using-with-lookup-mon @Veeram help me out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867811/how-to-do-user-already-there-update-if-not-there-create-in-particular-collecti

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the `groupname` from the `Usergroup`, `split` it to array of two group name using `str.split(',')` and then query the `Group` for two `groupname` as follow:

```
    Usergroup.findOne({ mobilenumber: 0509867865 }, function(err, usergroup) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        if (!usergroup) {
            return res.status(404).send('Not Found');
        }
        console.log(usergroup.groupname);

        var groupname   = usergroup.groupname;
        var groups      = groupname.split(',');
        var messages    = {};

        for (var i = groups.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Group.find({ groupname: groups[i] }, function(err, group) {
                if (err) {
                    return handleError(res, err);
                }
                messages[group.groupname] = group.message;
            });
            if (i == 0) {
                return res.status(200).json(messages);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: i am getting empty object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867811/how-to-do-user-already-there-update-if-not-there-create-in-particular-collecti